# Why use voltsql, there is an error Couldn't find log4j configuration file

Tags: voltdb

After I installed voltsql successfully, the following error occurred while executing voltsql

```
[whz@izbp16d6c3ttl701mgdkc7z voltdb]$ ./bin/voltsql 
> SHOW tables;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Couldn't find log4j configuration file.
```

how to solve this problem ？

Comment: What version of VoltDB are you using, and what OS?

Comment: 9.0 and centos7.6

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the README, including installing the additional dependencies? https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/tree/master/lib/python/voltsql